# "Previously sent invitations" shows HTML entities

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The "previously sent invitations" page on careers shows raw HTML entities:

```
John Doe &lt;johndoe@googlemail.com&gt;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the heads-up, this should be fixed.