# Careers have page to list applications sent

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I found [an issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91960/previously-sent-invitations-shows-html-entities) mentioning the existence of a page where there's a listing of all the applications one has sent...

That was dated back in 2011 though, today there is no (apparent?) way to view the sent job applications in careers.stackoverflow.com

Comment: So the question you're asking is "Where can I find a list of the applications I've sent?"?

Answer (score 1):

The linked post was talking about Careers invitations, which you can find a list of on the [page that you can also send them from](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/invitations). This is linked from the side bar of your profile:

[image: invitations link]

Actual job applications that you've sent are available from the "messages" link at the top of the Careers website, under the "Job Applications" section of the sidebar:

[image: job applications link]